# How to disable loopback packets in NDIS protocol driver

Tags: windows, driver, network-protocols, ndis

How do I disable receiving loopback packets in protocol driver?
The scenario is, my protocol driver is receiving packets from one adapter and sending it over to another. (like `eth0 -> eth1`).

Interested only in IPv4,

```
#define NPROT_ETH_TYPE               0x0008 //IPv4
```

The filter is defined as,

```
#define NPROTO_PACKET_FILTER  ( NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_NO_LOCAL|    \
                                NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_DIRECTED/*|    \
                                NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_MULTICAST|   \
                                NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_BROADCAST*/)
```

The receiving side is checking for loopback packets as shown below,

```
    // Leave the packet if loopback flag is set.
    if( NdisTestNblFlag( pNetBufList, NDIS_NBL_FLAGS_IS_LOOPBACK_PACKET ))
    {
        //
        // Ndisprot is not interested in this NetBufferList, return the
        // NetBufferList back to the miniport if the miniport gave us
        // ownership of it.
        //
        break;
    }
```

and when I send packets down the road, the `SendFlags` is set to zero to avoid loopback as per MSDN.

```
NdisSendNetBufferLists(        
                pOpenContext->BindingHandle,
                pNetBufferList,
                NDIS_DEFAULT_PORT_NUMBER,
                0);
```

Even after raising all these hurdles, my prottest is receiving loopback packets, as it is evident from wireshark.

Any idea?

Using NDIS6.0, ndisprot60, Dev: Win7, Test VM: Win2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're setting `NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_NO_LOCAL` and sending the NBLs without the `NDIS_SEND_FLAGS_CHECK_FOR_LOOPBACK` flag, then NDIS won't deliver loopback packets to you.

Wireshark isn't showing you what *your* protocol receives.  Each protocol can receive a custom set of traffic.  So Wireshark is only showing you what Wireshark receives :)

Comment: also, could you explain what happens if I read from one NIC and write to another without modifying the destination MAC, it creates a loop right?

Comment: Yes, it generally would, if the two NICs are on the same subnet.

Comment: hmmmm, may be I'm not seeing things correctly. :) Even though the two NICs are on different subnet (actually NIC one in 192.168.x.x and another in 10.10.x.x), when I read from NIC1 and write to NIC2, I'm picking up loopback. But when I modified the destination MAC to that of NIC2, the problem solved! Any idea?

Comment: I meant "subnet" in the layer-2 sense; any two nodes behind the same router.